# No Sub Main was not found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, function, compiler-errors, program-entry-point

Beginner! Trying to compile and I get the error no Sub Main found. I need a function and trying to call a function and perform command. I am trying to set a field in my program based on my selection. Not sure how to add a sub main when I already have things I cannot add it to. Im confused and new...

```
Imports JDA.Intactix.Automation
Imports JDA.Intactix.Automation.Space




Module Module1
Public Class Fixtures
    Inherits JDA.Intactix.Automation.Space.Fixture
    Public FixtureField As Object


    Public Function ForFixtures() As String

    End Function

    Public Sub CallFunctionForFixtures()

        Dim SegNum As Integer
        Dim LocID As Integer
        Dim NewName As Double
        Dim Name As String
        SegNum = JDA.Intactix.Automation.SpaceSegmentFields.Number
        LocID = JDA.Intactix.Automation.SpaceFixtureFields.LocationID
        Name = JDA.Intactix.Automation.FloorFixtureFields.Name
        NewName = JDA.Intactix.Automation.SpaceSegmentFields.Name & 
JDA.Intactix.Automation.SpaceFixtureFields.LocationID
        If Name = 1 Then SetFixtureField(FixtureField, Name, NewName)


    End Sub

    Private Overloads Sub SetFixtureField(FixtureField As Object, Name As 
String, newName As String)
        Name = JDA.Intactix.Automation.FloorFixtureFields.Name
        newName = JDA.Intactix.Automation.SpaceSegmentFields.Name & 
     JDA.Intactix.Automation.SpaceFixtureFields.LocationID
 End Sub
 End Class
 End Module
```

Edited code, added:
    `Public Sub Main() Call Function() ForFixtures() Dim SegNum 
     As Integer Dim 
     LocID As Integer Dim NewName As Double Dim Name As String SegNum = 
     JDA.Intactix.Automation.SpaceSegmentFields.Number LocID = 
     JDA.Intactix.Automation.SpaceFixtureFields.LocationID Name = 
     JDA.Intactix.Automation.FloorFixtureFields.Name NewName = 
     JDA.Intactix.Automation.SpaceSegmentFields.Name & 
     JDA.Intactix.Automation.SpaceFixtureFields.LocationID If Name = 1 Then 
     SetFixtureField(FixtureField, Name, NewName) End Sub –`

but still says not found

Comment: Sub `Main` is the entry point to your program. On creating a new project, vs automatically adds it for you. Why did you remove it?

Comment: I added the Sub Main and i still get the error.

Comment: Please don't put more than one short line of code in a comment. Click the edit link and add this to your question formatted as code.

Comment: added to edit in main question

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project and select properties

[image]

Click on the dropdown "Startup object"

[image]

If Sub Main isn't there, add this code to Module1

```
Sub Main()
    CallFunctionForFixtures()
End Sub
```

Then select it in the dropdown again

Comment: Maybe you could add a note about the need to disable the Application Framework, in case the OP's Project has a graphic interface.

Comment: @Jimi i didn't see anything in the question about a UI but if it comes up we can change it.

Comment: No, there's nothing in the question. It was a *just in case* type of comment. Because of the `JDA Intactix` stuff.